# CMake undefined symbol to extern

Tags: makefile, cmake, extern

I am trying to convert a Makefile project to a CMake project. The project has a file a.cxx that has an `extern` function declaration:

```
extern int shared_int;
extern void say_hello(void);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        say_hello();
        return 0;
}
```

The definition to that function is in b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int shared_int = 5;

void say_hello()
{
        printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

and my CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
project(extern_example)

add_executable(extern_example a.cxx b.c)
```

If I change the `printf` to be used in a.cc to print `shared_int`, it works fine, but when I try to use `say_hello` from a.cxx, I get

```
CMakeFiles/extern_example.dir/a.cxx.o: In function `main':
a.cxx:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `say_hello()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/extern_example.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'extern_example' failed
make[2]: *** [extern_example] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/extern_example.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/extern_example.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The error makes it look like b.c is not being linked correctly in the executable, but then why would `shared_int` be available?

I have tried to make this as general as possible, but the files in question are [on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/tmidas/midas/src/b8b07b930404/examples/experiment/?at=develop) (Makefile and analyzer.c/h are of interest) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/tmidas/midas/src/b8b07b930404c61a1859816d018cffe0956f6b92/src/mana.cxx?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default) is the file that I'm calling A.cxx. I have also trimmed off other includes and links in the compile commands, but I can post those if necessary.

Comment: In C++ code extern definitions should starts with `extern "C"` for being compatible with C definitions. Your problem's generalization is hard to understand: `CMakeLists.txt` creates executable `exec`, but links `analizer`; we can only guess, which symbols are listed in `undefined reference to` messages. Create [mcve], please.

Comment: I have changed the example to a more complete one and it has made me realize that I should use `extern "C"` instead of `extern` to work. But why does just `extern` work with the previous Makefile setup? Maybe the Makefile was forcing a C++ compiler for both?

Comment: Yes, using C++ for C code could be a reason, why simple `extern` works with makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with function definitions in a.cxx defined as

```
extern void f(void);
```

rather than

```
extern "C" void f(void);
```

or

```
extern "C" {
    void f(void);
}
```

Without specifying the C-style `extern`, the compiler mangles the function names, which are unable to be read by b.c.